# Is it possible to get yapf to ignore portions of a file?

Tags: python, snakemake, yapf

I'm using a python-dsl called snakemake that looks like this:

```
from bx.intervals.cluster import ClusterTree

from epipp.config import system_prefix, include_prefix, config, expression_matrix
config["name"] = "correlate_chip_regions_and_rna_seq"

bin_sizes = {"H3K4me3": 1000, "PolII": 200, "H3K27me3": 200}

rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/{bin_size}_{modification}.bed", zip,
               bin_size=bin_sizes.values(), modification=bin_sizes.keys())

rule get_gene_expression:
    input:
        expression_matrix
    output:
        "data/expression/series.csv"
    run:
        expression_matrix = pd.read_table(input[0])
        expression_series = expression_matrix.sum(1).sort_values(ascending=False)
        expression_series.to_csv(output[0], sep=" ")
```

I'd like to run yapf on the stuff within `run:` blocks.

Is it possible to get yapf to ignore the stuff that does not exist in python, like the `rule` keywords and so on and only use it on specific portions of the file?

Comment: I see that yapf has a `--lines` option.  

Maybe what you want to do could be achieved with the help of a first processing of your snakefile to determine which lines are to be skipped and which are to be processed?

Comment: No, still got a syntax error for the snakemake specific code even if I told it only to format lines that were valid Python :)

Comment: Maybe it has to do with indenting. The python parts within rules are more indented than they  would be if they were parts of a normal python script.

Comment: Nah, it finds the syntax error in the initial parsing step :)

Comment: Then another option might be to somehow extract the valid python blocks, reformat them separately, then reassemble them. A rather "unfun" task...

Comment: That was my original thought. Exchange `rule bla:` with `for bla in bla`, run yapf, then switch back. Rather hackish though. Perhaps I should ask the yapf developers for pointers.

Answer (score 7):

Yes its possible, by using the `# yapf: disable` and `# yapf: enable` comment directives.

Example from the [readme](https://github.com/google/yapf#why-does-yapf-destroy-my-awesome-formatting):

```
# yapf: disable
FOO = {
    # ... some very large, complex data literal.
}

BAR = [
    # ... another large data literal.
]
# yapf: enable
```

You can also disable formatting for a single literal like this:

```
BAZ = {
    (1, 2, 3, 4),
    (5, 6, 7, 8),
    (9, 10, 11, 12),
}  # yapf: disable
```